# Background Stills Scrolls on Mobile With Menu Open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am going to get roasted for this but I've searched on StackOverflow and tried to implement the suggestions provided to no avail. Whenever I am using the menu on my website (on mobile devices) the main page still scrolls when I move my thumb and it causes glitches with the display. I cannot get it to lock in place when the menu is open.

**Here's what I've tried**

- Position: relative (on body)
- Height: 100% (on body)
- Overflow: Hidden (applied to Body when you click to open menu)

None of those have worked. As you can see, the page still scrolls on mobile. Currently my live example shows this:

https://www.brotherhoodgaming.net

Any suggestions are welcome. I'd prefer a CSS solution to this rather than Javascript or Jquery (although Jquery toggleClass is fine as long as CSS is the baseline solution).

Comment: Since I'm having a lot of trouble re-creating this I'll give you some semi-blind suggestions. Try setting .show {display:block} or removing the overflow-y scroll on your .viewmenu.

Comment: Do you happen to have an android phone? I wonder if this is somehow an Apple mobile issue. I'll have to do some testing. In the mean time I will try adding {display:block}.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remove the overflow-y from .viewmenu since my menu may need to be able to scroll while the body needs to be fixed.